# How to create transactional fixture with peewee_async and pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio, peewee, fixture

I want to use transactions for tests with the `pytest`'s fixtures as follows:

```py
import pytest
from app.db.clients import (
    get_database,  # Returns instance of the class PooledMySQLDatabase
    BaseManager  # Extends the class peewee_async.Manager
)

db = get_database()
db.set_allow_sync(False)

objects = BaseManager(database=db)

@pytest.yield_fixture
async def transactional():
    async with objects.transaction() as trx:
        yield trx
        await trx.rollback()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('transactional')
@pytest.mark.asyncio:
async def test_transactional_fixture():
    pass  # Do something with the objects
```

However the code above doesn't work as expected in return tests are collected but aren't executing. Looks like pytest tries to yield tests infinite. I have no idea how to run transactional tests with such technology stack. Could someone help me, please?

[image]

P.S. The code snippet above is just represention of the project's workflow (screenshot was taken from real project).